# Canvas stays behind content control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have user control in WPF. There is a grid, and it has two children. One canvas and one content control. I want this transparent canvas over the content control, but it stays behind it.

```
<Grid x:Name="g1" Margin="0" Background="Black">
    <ContentControl x:Name="cc1" Panel.ZIndex="100" Content="{Binding Content}"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="c1" Panel.ZIndex="500">
        <Label Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10" Content="Text 1" Foreground="White" />
        <Label Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Right="10" Content="Text 2" Foreground="White" />
        <Label Canvas.Bottom="10" Canvas.Left="10" Content="Text 3" Foreground="White" />
        <Label Canvas.Bottom="10" Canvas.Right="10" Content="Text 4" Foreground="White" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried to swap Canvas with ContentControl so your ContentControl goes first and then Canvas? As far as I remember, that's the way Z-order is determined in XAML.

Comment: Change the order of declaration, i.e. ContentControl  before Canvas.

Comment: I've edited my code just like you said, changed order of elements and gave ZIndex, but canvas still stays behind the content control.

Comment: I have reproduced this example already edited with the solutions users gave to you, and it's good. Content Control appears behind canvas.

Comment: So, maybe the problem caused by content I generate in content control? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can either

- Declare the Canvas after the ContentControl within the Grid.

or

- Set the `ZIndex` property of the Canvas - the higher the value, the more 'forward' a control will appear.

Answer (score 0):

In any Panel, elements are shown behind to top, from the first declared one.

So, you'll simply have to declare the Canvas after:

```
<Grid x:Name="g1" Margin="0" Background="Black">
    <ContentControl x:Name="cc1" Content="{Binding Content}"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="c1">
        <Label Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10" Content="Text 1" Foreground="White" />
        <Label Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Right="10" Content="Text 2" Foreground="White" />
        <Label Canvas.Bottom="10" Canvas.Left="10" Content="Text 3" Foreground="White" />
        <Label Canvas.Bottom="10" Canvas.Right="10" Content="Text 4" Foreground="White" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Or, set the Canvas Panel.ZIndex property to 1 or higher.

```
<Canvas x:Name="c1" Panel.ZIndex="1">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="g1" Margin="0" Background="Black">
        <ContentControl x:Name="cc1" Content="{Binding Content}" Background="White"/>
        <Canvas x:Name="c1" Background="Red">
            <Label Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10" Content="Text 1" Foreground="White" />
            <Label Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Right="10" Content="Text 2" Foreground="White" />
            <Label Canvas.Bottom="10" Canvas.Left="10" Content="Text 3" Foreground="White" />
            <Label Canvas.Bottom="10" Canvas.Right="10" Content="Text 4" Foreground="White" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

I added two color, White for the `ContentControl` and Red for `Canvas` for you to identify.
Has you can see, with this example you only can see the color Red, meaning that `Canvas` is above `ContentControl`.